# SSRS not accepting table type (integer_list_tbltype) as parameter

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a stored proc which has the input param as integer_list_tbltype. I can run the proc like this

```
DECLARE @mylist integer_list_tbltype
INSERT @mylist(n) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4)
exec <Proc_Name> @mylist
```

When I try to add this under SSRS (Sql reporting services 2008) as shared database, then I get error.

**Operand type clash: nvarchar is incompatible with integer_list_tbltype**

Any workaround for this ?

Ved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been frustrated by the same issue recently. I *think* this happens because SSRS always sends every parameter as nvarchar when actually invoking the queries that the report needs to run. There's no way that SQL Server will correctly interpret an nvarchar as the table type that you're trying to use, so you get that error.

I just blogged about a potential solution/workaround where you use a custom code block to populate the table variable before invoking the stored procedure:

http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2012/06/21/using-table-valued-parameters-with-sql-server-reporting-services.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Alas, a multi-valued parameter in SSRS doesn't work as you expected, it doesn't behave like a table or anything alike.

Instead, SSRS will replace the parameter in your SQL query with a comma-separated list of all the values. So your example will be sent to SQL Server like this:

```
exec <Proc_Name> 1,2,3,4
```

The way to use a multi-valued parameter in SSRS ([see this, for example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337396%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)) is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM MyNumbers WHERE MyNumbers.Nmbr IN (@mylist)
```

Which is sent to SQL Server as:

```
SELECT * FROM MyNumbers WHERE MyNumbers.Nmbr IN (1,2,3,4)
```

---

PS. The error message you post might also indicate that your parameter type is set to "Text" in SSRS, where you seem to mean "Integer".